How to rectify the error : Length of values (0) does not match length of index (30)
Code is as
# Create range to test different lags
p_params = range(1, 31)

# Create empty list to hold mean absolute error scores
maes = []
# Iterate through all values of p in `p_params`
for p in range(30):
    # Build model
    model =AutoReg(y_train,lags=p).fit()
     # Make predictions on training data, dropping null values caused by lag
    y_pred = model.predict(start=p, end=len(y_train)-1)
    # Calculate mean absolute error for training data vs predictions
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train[p:], y_pred)
     # Put list `maes` into Series with index `p_params`
    mae_series = pd.Series(maes, name="mae", index =p_params)

error is
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 15
     13 mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train[p:], y_pred)
     14  # Put list `maes` into Series with index `p_params`
---> 15 mae_series = pd.Series(maes, name="mae", index =p_params)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:461, in Series.__init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    459     index = default_index(len(data))
    460 elif is_list_like(data):
--> 461     com.require_length_match(data, index)
    463 # create/copy the manager
    464 if isinstance(data, (SingleBlockManager, SingleArrayManager)):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py:571, in require_length_match(data, index)
    567 """
    568 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    569 """
    570 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 571     raise ValueError(
    572         "Length of values "
    573         f"({len(data)}) "
    574         "does not match length of index "
    575         f"({len(index)})"
    576     )

ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (30)

I have tried the following code
# Create range to test different lags
p_params = range(1, 31)

# Create empty list to hold mean absolute error scores
maes = []
# Iterate through all values of p in `p_params`
for p in range(30):
    # Build model
    model =AutoReg(y_train,lags=p).fit()
     # Make predictions on training data, dropping null values caused by lag
    y_pred = model.predict(start=p, end=len(y_train)-1)
    # Calculate mean absolute error for training data vs predictions
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train[p:], y_pred)
     # Put list `maes` into Series with index `p_params`
    mae_series = pd.Series(maes, name="mae", index =p_params)

i expect a print of column having maes

Welcome to SO! Please format your code.

Use p_params = list(range(1, 31)). You can't use an iterator multiple times.
